# Play audio from url with Android Media Player issue

Tags: android, ios, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to develop an app to listen to streaming mp3 files uploaded to server amazon aws (S3), I tried any type of code in the various tutorials on the web and I tried any solution present. The error that occurs to me is when I try to set the URL of the audio file through the official documentation of Android.

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

A "null" mediaplayer object is returned to me. The same url work on iOS (swift).

Does anyone have a solution?